# Regex to get at least X lines between Keywords

Tags: regex

I am trying to match using `regex` all defintions of some SQL Stored Procedures with a length of at least 1000 lines from within a large script file. These start with `CREATE PROCEDURE` and the only reliable indicator for an end is the `CREATE PROCEDURE` of a new proc.

```
(?i)(CREATE PROCEDURE)(.*\n){10,}(CREATE PROCEDURE|EOF)
```

Here is an example and what I have tried so far:

https://regex101.com/r/yVOZJk/1

I fail to negate the `CREATE PROCEDURE` keywords within the boundaries.

P.S.: The script file only contains stored procedures, no need to think about other boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a repeating pattern which checks if the line starts with `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `EOF`.

If it does not, then match the whole line. If you only want the match, you cold omit the capturing group around CREATE PROCEDURE.

```
(?i)CREATE PROCEDURE.*(?:\r?\n(?!CREATE PROCEDURE|EOF).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` Inline modifier case insensitive
- `CREATE PROCEDURE.*` Match CREATE PROCEDURE followed by matching 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!CREATE PROCEDURE|EOF)` Match newline, assert what is directly on the right is not CREATE PROCEDURE| or EOF
- `.*` If that is the case, match any char except newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYVkAf/1)

Comment: May be I didn't understand the problem but it will also match `CREATE PROCEDURE TheEOF`

Comment: @anubhava You are right, it does match that. (The downvote is not mine) I think appending a quantifier to match a minimum amount of lines can prevent that `(?i)CREATE PROCEDURE.*(?:\r?\n(?!CREATE PROCEDURE|EOF).*){6,}` https://regex101.com/r/oJBI74/1

Comment: Thanks, this works just as expected. I replaced the last `*` with the quantifier `{1000,}` for the least number of lines to filter.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex:

```
(?i)CREATE PROCEDURE(?:.*\n){11,}(?=CREATE PROCEDURE|EOF|\z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yVOZJk/2)

- `(?:.*\n){11,}` expression will match 11 or more lines following starting keyword `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Reason why this is one more than `10` because first `.*\n` is used to match same line start starts with `CREATE PROCEDURE`.
- Lookahead assertion `(?=CREATE PROCEDURE|EOF|\z)` makes sure there is a presence of `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `EOF` or end of input ahead of current position.

Comment: Thx for the effort and the explanation.